# Why isn't my Getter function working with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema, getter

I have a getter on the price property of my schema.
For some reason, my getter function is not working when I try to query a document from my MongoDB database. The price value comes back exactly as I have it saved in my database, as opposed to a rounded number via Math.floor(v). Fyi, my setter works fine in the same scenario. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 const schema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true },
  isPublished: Boolean,
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: function (v) {
      return this.isPublished;
    },
    uppercase:true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    get: function (v) {
      return Math.floor(v);
    },
  },
});

const Documents = mongoose.model("Documents", schema);

    async function myQuery(id) {
    const result = await Documents.findById(id);
      if (!result) return debug("Not found...");
      debug(result);
    }
    
    myQuery("60348d30e7b9bf3878170955");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true },
    isPublished: Boolean,
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: function (v) {
            return this.isPublished;
        },
        uppercase: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        get: function (v) {
            return Math.floor(v);
        },
    },
} {
    toObject: { getters: true, setters: true },
    toJSON: { getters: true, setters: true },
    runSettersOnQuery: true
});
```

Add the following configuration to your schema and give it a try.

Comment: I added those properties but am still getting back my price Number unchanged.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am facing same, even after adding toObject, toJSON

Answer (score 0):

The getter is only applied when you access the specific property of the document. So if you rewrite your function as follows, the getter will be applied to the `price` field:

```
async function myQuery(id) {
    const result = await Documents.findById(id);
    if (!result) return debug("Not found...");
    debug(result.price);
}

myQuery("60348d30e7b9bf3878170955");
```